# A process send encoded(UnixRights)file descriptors by out of band to B process , why B process receive data different from A process

Tags: go, file-descriptor, unix-socket

like lower position comment, A send [16 0 0 0 255 255 0 0 1 0 0 0 9 0 0 0],B get [16 0 0 0 255 255 0 0 1 0 0 0 8 0 0 0],different with 8 and 9 . 9 was file id in the A process .

A process

```
lf, err := listen.File()
uc := unixConn.(*net.UnixConn)
buf := make([]byte, 1)
rights := syscall.UnixRights(int(lf.Fd()))
fmt.Println("rights",rights)
// rights [16 0 0 0 255 255 0 0 1 0 0 0 9 0 0 0]
n, oobn, err := uc.WriteMsgUnix(rights, rights, nil)
```

B process

```
buf := make([]byte, 1)
oob := make([]byte, 1024)
_, oobn, _, _, err := uc.ReadMsgUnix(buf, oob)

fmt.Prinln(oob[0:oobn])

//16 0 0 0 255 255 0 0 1 0 0 0 8 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I found reason . cause process send to other process file description is not same . 9 has used in A process ,so B process use 8 .